# using the inject method to sum instances of an array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an instance variable called `@jdc_array`, on inspection its contents look like this:

```
"[#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<JobDeliveryCost id: 13, job_id: 53, delivery_cost_id: 1, cost_per_unit: 50.0, quantity: 3, timing: \"install\", created_at: \"2014-07-23 15:20:34\", updated_at: \"2014-07-23 15:20:34\">, #<JobDeliveryCost id: 15, job_id: 53, delivery_cost_id: 1, cost_per_unit: 50.0, quantity: 5, timing: \"install\", created_at: \"2014-07-23 15:57:45\", updated_at: \"2014-07-23 15:57:45\">, #<JobDeliveryCost id: 18, job_id: 53, delivery_cost_id: 1, cost_per_unit: 44.0, quantity: 1, timing: \"breakdown\", created_at: \"2014-07-23 18:27:20\", updated_at: \"2014-07-23 18:27:20\">, #<JobDeliveryCost id: 19, job_id: 53, delivery_cost_id: 1, cost_per_unit: 22.0, quantity: 1, timing: \"install\", created_at: \"2014-07-23 18:27:28\", updated_at: \"2014-07-23 18:27:28\">, #<JobDeliveryCost id: 20, job_id: 53, delivery_cost_id: 1, cost_per_unit: 3.0, quantity: 1, timing: \"install\", created_at: \"2014-07-23 18:28:45\", updated_at: \"2014-07-23 18:28:45\">]>, nil]"
```

I want to sum all the instances of `cost_per_unit:` so I created this method

```
  def calculate_delivery_total(array)
    array.map(&:cost_per_unit).inject(0, &:+) 
  end
```

and call the method like so:

```
  def index 
    if get_deliverable
      @jdc_array=(@job.job_delivery_costs.any? ? [@job.job_delivery_costs,@new_delivery] : [@new_delivery])
      @new_delivery = @deliverable.job_delivery_costs.build
    end
    set_job_delivery_cost
    @total = calculate_delivery_total(@jdc_array)
  end
```

But bizzarely I get this error!?!

```
formal argument cannot be an instance variable def calculate_delivery_total(@array)
```

Three questions. Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it? Third, Is it good form to be doing such stuff in the controller, or should I do it elsewhere and how?

UPDATE

so following SO poster's suggestions i changed the method to this

```
  def calculate_delivery_total(array)
    array.map(&:cost_per_unit).inject(0, &:+)
  end
```

but i still get this error

```
undefined method `cost_per_unit' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_JobDeliveryCost:0x00000106172788>
```

I can do this in the console, why wont it work here?!

Comment: What line is that error on?

Comment: This error is a syntax error - it has nothing to do with the _value_ of `@jdc_array` - chances are you forgot an `end` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @UriAgassi can you check now?

Comment: From the error message it seems that your method signature is `def calculate_delivery_total(@array)` - you can't use `@` in argument names - it should be `def calculate_delivery_total(array)` ...

Comment: @UriAgassi thanks for your help, i added an update...this is so annoying

Comment: For the undefined method error, try using the 'to_a' and 'compact' I suggested in my answer. Also I suspect you may be running different code in the two places. Can you ensure you've copied the exact code that's failing?

Comment: @UriAgassi's answer found what I missed - the CollectionProxy is in an array itself. Doh!

Comment: Thanks for your links and help though man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@jdc_array` can be one of two values:

```
[@job.job_delivery_costs,@new_delivery]
```

Or

```
[@new_delivery]
```

I don't know what `@new_delivery` is, but `job_delivery_costs` returns a *collection* (more specifically a [`CollectionProxy`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html)) of `JobDeliveryCost` objects, which means you have a collection inside a collection.

On the other hand, `@new_delivery` might be `nil` (as per your sample data at the beginning of the post), probably because *you assign a value to it after you've put it in the array* (the value in the array will not change) - you need to swap those lines.

My suggestion is to change the method to receive two arguments - the list of delivery costs, and the new delivery, something like this:

```
def calculate_delivery_total(deliveries, new_delivery)
  total = 0
  unless deliveries.nil?
    total = deliveries.map(&:cost_per_unit)
  end
  unless new_delivery.nil?
    total += new_delivery.cost_per_unit
  end
  total
end
```

and your `index` code should probably look like this:

```
  def index 
    if get_deliverable
      @new_delivery = @deliverable.job_delivery_costs.build
    end
    set_job_delivery_cost
    @total = calculate_delivery_total(@job.job_delivery_costs,@new_delivery)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, I use a facade pattern to prepare data for the view. This avoids calculation in the view or controller and promotes separation of concerns and reuse.

Here's a resource, but I may expand in an edit.

https://medium.com/@ryakh/facade-pattern-on-rails-d65b86cdb5b1

---

For the error, it's a guess but could it be that the last element of the array is a nil? Have you tried a .to_a and a compact?

`def calculate_delivery_total(array)`
`array.to_a.compact.map(&:cost_per_unit).inject(0, &:+)`
`end`

Comment: It's confusing because the error should be 'undefined method for nil' instead of syntax error.

If this doesn't help, it would help to provide rails and ruby versions.

Also the piece of code that returns your @jdc_array.

Comment: my bad @AFaderDarkly, i had a trailing *. but still this doesnt work 
 def calculate_delivery_total(@array)
@array.map(&:cost_per_unit).inject(0, &:+)
  end

Comment: you're using an @ in your method params. `def thing(@nope)` is not valid syntax.

Comment: In this case, `def calculate_delivery_total(@array)`